# Cant run code and function call passed as string inside settimeout

Tags: javascript

I want to run code using settimeout.
I have this function:

```
 function passing_functions(thefunction)
    {
    var my_function ="res="+thefunction+ "(); if (res==true){another_function} "
```

and on this call :

```
 passing_functions("load_database");
```

I have this string:

```
res = load_database();if (res==true){another_function}
```

Ok, I'm unable to use it inside settimetout

```
settimeout(function() {my_funtion},100}
settimeout(function() {my_funtion()},100}
settimeout(eval(my_funtion),100}
settimeout(my_funtion),100}
settimeout(my_funtion()),100}
```

etc ---
I have always an error or nothing....

Also I have tried to use "this." as prefix for "thefunction" without success.

Could anybody help me ? What I'm doing wrong ?
Thanks

NOTE:
(I want to create an array of things to be executed.
I could use passing_functions(load_database); but then I receive all the code instead the function. This is because by now I'm using string to pass the code.
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All your "function calls" end with a `}` instead of a `)` or have the closing `)` somewhere in between. [The signature is `setTimeout(func, time)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout), i.e. the function accepts two arguments, another function and a number. The arguments are put between the `(...)` and separated by commas. Assuming that `my_funtion` is actually a function, `setTimeout(my_funtion, 100)` will be valid.

However it seems you are trying to run JavaScript code that is inside a string. Don't do that. JavaScript is a powerful language where functions are first class citizens. So instead of passing the name of the function and build a string, just pass the function directly:

```
function passing_functions(thefunction) {
    setTimeout(
        function() { // first argument: a function
            var res = thefunction(); // call the function passed as argument
            if (res) {
                // I assume you actually want to *call* that function
                // just putting another_function there doesn't do anything
                another_function(); 
            }
        },
        100 // second argument: the delay
    );
}

// the function load_database must exist at the time you pass it
passing_functions(load_database);
```

Whether or not this is what you want I cannot say, but it should give you an idea how to properly solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks. i'm going to try . And.... thefunction data received in your example is all the code , isn't . Is there any way to get the name of thefunction rather than the code ? (of course I could define a function which receive the code and short name....)  Thanks again

Comment: In most browsers, functions have a the unofficial [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). Or if you only have the name of the function and the function is *global*, you can run it with `window[nameofthefunction]()`. But again, there is seldom a reason to have to use any of these. Why can't you pass the function directly?

Comment: I had an alert (function code ) to see what was happen. That alert shows me the whole code....  Thanks. A last question, when you use var res= thefunction() you have all the code "linked" to res instea a simple function call, isn't ?  Thanks

Comment: Well, if you try to alert a function, it will show you the code of the function. I'm not sure what you mean by the code is "linked". I simple assign the return value of `thefunction` to `res`.